# Access Crate with postman through REST API?

Tags: rest, crate

Can postman be used to access CrateIO through the REST API ? How is the syntax different from the curl syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use Postman to invoke `POST` requests against the `/_sql` HTTP endpoint of Crate.IO, there is no difference in the syntax.

Simply use `POST` as the request method, and the URL of the Crate instance.
Select `raw` POST body and specify the JSON as if you would write it with curl. The JSON requires at least the `stmt` property which contains the SQL statement that should be executed on the server.

[image: Using Postman app to make HTTP requests against Crate.IO]

Documentation of the HTTP endpoint: https://crate.io/docs/reference/sql/rest.html